# Blank Email issue in magento for new order

Tags: magento

In my magento website As soon as someone places order , an email is sent to his/her emailid. In the email the subject is correct but there is no body in the message, i mean the message comes blank.
i **added new template** from **Transactional Emails** section and associated this template with the Order from **configuration->sales emails**. but still my subject of the template reaches to mails but not the body. the message body remains empty always.

please help me solve this issue

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some error during rendering the email template. Try to replace your email template body with something simple.

Comment: my dear answerer ! in message i even used simple text but it was also not working. i mean not going with email message body. i tried it in many ways by changing the message body.
it seems to me that either i have missed out some settings regarding the emails or there is some error in coding somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't trigger any error when the template is not returned/processed properly.

The trace is:
`Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` - sendNewOrderEmail()

`Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php` - send()

`Mage/Core/Model/Template.php` - send()

Some things to check first - is the email valid for send, see the conditions below:

```
public function isValidForSend()
{   
    return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
        && $this->getSenderName()
        && $this->getSenderEmail()
        && $this->getTemplateSubject();
}
```

Another thing to look for:

If you copy-pasted some of the email content you might have some characters in the email that are not ASCII. This causes a crash when the template is parsed and there is no error logged/displayed. 
This can be checked by using the standard Magento email template and if that works and your custom template doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the cause of the error was the vars:

```
{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}
{{config path='general/store_information/phone'}}
```

If these are deleted/substituted, then the emails are being sent without errors.